# Bidirectional iterator from char * buffer with size

Tags: c++, string, iterator, buffer

I can't seem to be able to find an easy simple solution, how to get bidirectional iterator from `char *buffer` with defined `bufferSize`. I don't want to copy the buffer to `std::string` (too expensive), I just want something like `std_whatever::buffer_wrapper myWrappedBuffer(myBuffer, mySize);` and then use `myWrappedBuffer.begin()` and `myWrappedBuffer.end()` in `<algorithm>` functions. What is the simplest way to do that? I really don't want to implement the iterator myself. I know there is `boost::string_ref` and maybe `std::string_view`, but I don't want to use boost just for this and can't use c++17.

Comment: It was a silly question, but might be helpful for someone in the future ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char *b=buffer;
```

This is your beginning iterator.

```
char *e=buffer+buffersize;
```

This is your ending iterator.

Plain, garden variety pointers meet all requirements of not just bi-directional, but random access iterators, and can generally be used anywhere any kind of an iterator is required, and they'll work just like one. All (well-written) iterator-based templates will work with pointers just fine.

You can even feed them to `std::iterator_traits`, and get meaningful results. Try it yourself and see what happens.